# Redirect to an external page from a specific article - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm very new with drupal.

I have a blog, List of posts.
I need redirect a specific post to a specific external webpage, Is this possible ?

[image]

By example: I need to redirect the post (with the arrow red) to **www.facebook.com/somePage.** (if it's possible in other tab)

But the other posts should be redirect normally to its internal pages.

In this moment I have this configuration:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

1. Add a URL Redirect pointing from the 'node/#' URL to your external URL.
2. Render View as you have it now, and when you click the article Title it'll send you to the external page.

## Method 2

1. Install the 'Link' module.
2. Add a 'Link' field to your Content Type. Configure the link field to open links in a new window, and so on.
3. Add that new field to your View. Set it to not appear in display, so it can be used later. Move this link above your Title Field in the View, because the order matters.
4. Edit the Title field settings and use the Link field value as a Token for the Title field.